# Spectral sequence $B^1_{p,q}= B^\infty_{p,q}$ definition, nlab

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, spectral-sequences

In an introductory notes to spectral sequences, [nlab, Definition 1.26](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Introduction+to+Spectral+Sequences) we define

> $$B^r_{p,q} = \partial(F_{p+r-1} C_{p+q+1})$$

and

> $$B^\infty_{p,q}= \partial(F_{p}C_{p+q+1})$$

So what is the difference between $B^1_{p,q}$ and $B^\infty_{p,q}$? Or any references would help!

Comment: They must want $\cup_{r = 0}^{\infty} B_{p,q}^{r}$ or something for $B_{p,q}^{\infty}$. I agree that I can't make sense of the part you've included in the question (although this is not my area).

Comment: I don't know what the nlab meant. I won't answer definitively because I'm not an expert and some people will probably understand better what the nlab is saying, but one definition is to go back to $E^1_{p,q}$ : you can somehow see every $B^r_{p,q}$ as a quotient of a submodule (or subobject if you're woriking in an abelian category) of $E^1_{p,q}$, and so you can lift it to the corresponding submodule of $E^1_{p,q}$ and put $B^\infty_{p,q}$ as the union of all of these (similarly for $Z^\infty_{p,q}$ but you're taking the intersection)

Comment: Yea, of the references I know $B^\infty_{p,q}$ is the union, but this doesn't coincide with this one in nlab...

Comment: Based on consulting Weibel p.133 (supposedly the source of this), it should be $B^\infty_{p,q} = \partial (C_{p+q+1}) \cap F_pC/F_{p-1}C$. The definition given above is imprecise. $B^r_{p,q}$ lives inside $F_pC/F_{p-1}C$.

Comment: It is confirmed (https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/2402/spectral-sequence-of-a-filtered-complex/#Item_0) that it is a typo and that the page needs cleaning up.

Comment: A bit irritating to be told it is "obvious for small values of obvious". I take that to mean they don't intend people to learn from nlab. So, I would recommend that you consult other sources (like Weibel) for the spectral sequence of a filtered complex. Then, come back and it might be "obvious for small values of obvious".